# How to prevent tables filling up Oracles Recycle bin created by Hibernate via hibernate.ddl-auto: create-drop

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring-boot

Multiple of our spring boot applications in development use the hibernate flag `ddl-auto:create-drop` to initialize the database. Dropped tables get renamed and are moved to the Oracle recycle bin and our database guys told us there are thousands of tables piling up. Instead of only dropping those tables we should use the "PURGE" command to get rid of them permanently.

Is there a way to configure Hibernate to purge those tables? If not, is there another clean way to do this? A colleague suggested to write a cron job that purges those tables once in a while, but I hoped there is maybe a more "builtin" approach to this problem.

Comment: Can you configure Spring Boot to run post-deployment tasks? If so, make a call to `purge recyclebin;` (or maybe an anonymous PL/SQL block `begin execute immediate 'purge recyclebin'; end;`).

Comment: Yes that would probably be possible. I also considered to disable the recycle bin feature per "alter session" command completely.